# Is this Gradient Descent method or something else?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I'm reading a paper entitled "**Sdf-2-sdf: Highly accurate 3d object reconstruction"**
http://campar.in.tum.de/pub/slavcheva2016eccv/slavcheva2016eccv.pdf

To get the rigid transformation (translation and rotation) $\xi$ between 2 camera frames, in Eqn. (11)~(17), an error function $E_{geom}$ is created and optimized:
[image]

I can see the derivative is:

- $dE_{geom}/d\xi=\Sigma(\phi_{ref}-\phi_{cur}(\xi^k))▽_\xi\phi_{cur}(\xi^k)$

and if Gradient Descent (GD) method applied, seems the update part should be:

- $\xi^{k+1}=\xi^k+\alpha*dE_{geom}/d\xi$

but in Eqn. (13)~(16), a var $\xi^*$ is computed and used to update $\xi^{k+1}$. That seems not GD method to me.

What's the physical meaning of $\xi^*$? is there any tutorial (or keywords to google) on this optimization method?

Answer (score 2):

The gradient descent that you're looking for seems to be on equations (19) and (20), where they get the same equation that you did. As to your question, what they appear to be doing is described in the paper:

> We determine the relative transformation between two RGB-D frames by
>   setting the pose of the first one to identity and incrementally updating the other
>   one.

In that regard, $\xi^*$ is the identity pose that they are attempting to iterate the current estimated pose $\xi^k$ towards. Going off of the definition given by (16), it certainly seems that way- $\xi^*$ is defined specifically as the pose where the derivative of the error is zero, which is verifiable by plugging (16) into (15):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E_{geom}}{\mathrm{d}\xi^*}=\mathbf{A}\xi^*-\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{A*A^{-1}b}-\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{b}=0$$

In that way, they can determine through (17) the relative transformation of each frame- presume that the first is identity, and iterate the second to get back to the first. This is referred to in the paper as frame-to-frame camera tracking. They then take a selection of these frames, and apply a frame-to-model optimization (equations (19) and (20)) to get better approximation to the global weighted average.

So, to more accurately answer your question, $\xi^*$ is the first SDF, representative of identity. The second SDF is what they iterate from, to calculate the incremental difference. It becomes more evident what's going on if we do a bit of work on (17):

$$\xi^{k+1}=\xi^k+\beta(\xi^*-\xi^k)=\xi^k+\beta \xi^* - \beta \xi^k = (1-\beta)\xi^k+\xi^*$$

Since, naturally, $\beta$ is some step value in $[0,1)$, it's obvious that $(1-\beta)\lt1$. With that, we can determine that for any given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\xi^{k+n}=(1-\beta)^n \xi^k+(1-(1-\beta)^n)\xi^*$. You can see, then, that repeated iterations will converge to $\xi^*$.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I understand now, that eqn (13)~(17) is Newton's method for optimization. In general case, the main weakness of gradient descent (GD) is the slower convergence speed. When I try to reimplement this algorithm, however, Newton's method works well with the cost function converges correctly, yet the GD method doesn't converge at all. The GD should be easy to implement, and I checked my code carefully to avoid errors, but still no luck... any ideas?

Comment: Something that they mentioned in the paper is that all of the equations are being presented without the weights that would normally be added during implementation. Did you add those weights?

Comment: The weights has only two values "0/1". Voxels with `w=0` are simply omitted during solving Aξ=b, and voxels with `w=1` are simply added up. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Right, that's the weights for whether a voxel is visible or not. The global weighted average (9) is the key to making this all work.

Comment: I pushed the code to github here: https://github.com/zhangxaochen/sdf2sdf, in `main.cpp`, line 260: `initial_twist -= 1e-7 * delta_twist;` tries to do GD, can you check if it's correct?

Comment: It looks mostly good to me. How often do you recompute the weighted global average? The paper specifies that they only recompute it every 10 iterations, which might be the issue if you're recomputing it every iteration or not recomputing it at all.

Comment: Oh, I think I found an issue- line 242 seems to be multiplying by the transpose of the gradient. If you look at (19) in the paper, it is just multiplying by the gradient, not its transpose.

Comment: Ispil, I greatly appreciate your carefully reading the paper and my code :-) . On the "recompute" issue, it's the post process part, which seems not quite relevant; and on line 242, the "transpose" issue, it seems (19) to be problematic, because the gradient is of shape 1x6, while ξ is of shape 6x1, there should be a transpose to me.